# how do I refresh gridview after adding new row?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I made several research but cannot figure out the problem. I can add, remove or edit rows from database in the code. However, I could not refresh the grid.
I mean, when I add new row to gridview, it doesn't appear in it. After I recompile the code it appears. How can I refresh the gridview?

```
        Dim strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FIXEDCARD WHERE STKCODE = '" & TextEdit1.Text & "'"
    objCon.Close()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, objCon)
    objCon.Open()
    Dim dreader As SqlDataReader
    dreader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader


    If dreader.Read Then
        'Dim stk_ As String = dreader.GetString(dreader.GetOrdinal("STKCODE")).ToString()
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("already exists", "Info!", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        objCon.Close()

    Else
        dreader.Close()

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO FIXEDCARD(STKCODE, STKEXP, AUTHCODE, GRPCODE, SPECODE" & _
                                ", SPECODE2, SPECODE3, SPECODE4, SPECODE5, AMORTRATIO, AMORT," & _
                                "PURCH, SALES, RETUR, UNIT) VALUES('" & TextEdit1.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit2.Text & "', '" & TextEdit3.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit4.Text & "', '" & TextEdit5.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit6.Text & "', '" & TextEdit7.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit8.Text & "', '" & TextEdit9.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit10.Text & "', '" & TextEdit11.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit12.Text & "', '" & TextEdit13.Text & "'," & _
                                "'" & TextEdit14.Text & "', '" & TextEdit15.Text & "') "

        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objCon)
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objCon.Close()
    End If
```

RefreshGrid()
        Me.Close()

And also I try to write a refresh function that will refresh the gridview when I call it each button. However, I have been making a mistake but could not recognize it.

```
    Public Sub RefreshGrid()
    Dim T As New DataTable
    Dim strSQL = "Select * From FIXEDCARD"
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, objCon)
    T = CType(sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), System.Data.DataTable)
    GridView1.DataSource = T
End Sub
```

Comment: Refresh the grid the same way you load data to grid. What's the problem?

Comment: I got the problem **@reza** . 
`Dim strSQL = "Select * From FIXEDCARD"
        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, objCon)
        Dim dsx1 = New DataSet
        Dim adx1 As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, objCon)
        adx1.Fill(dsx1, "a")
        Dim t1 As DataTable = dsx1.Tables("a")
       fixed_grid.datasource = t1

Comment: Yes, that is what you need, You even don't need a `DataSet` and you can use a `DataTable` directly.

Comment: Not sure about that. I am gonna try it without using dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Public Function FillDataSet(query As String, ByVal ParamArray para() As Object) As DataTable

         dim _transaction As SqlTransaction
         Dim _command As SqlCommand

        _command = New SqlCommand(query, yourConnection)

        _ds = New DataSet
        _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_command )
        _command.Transaction = _transaction

        For i = 0 To para.Count - 1
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, para(i))
        Next

        _sqlda.Fill(_ds)

       return _ds.tables(0)

  End Function
```

call it

```
  GridControl1.datasource = Nothing
  GridControl1.datasource = FillDataSet(YourInsertQuery,YourParam)
  GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "Non-Query" in the refresh. This doesn't return a table value.

Try using the `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` method.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx